# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Fullscreen when 'PageWrap'(container) width: 1140px

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want Bootstrap 4 carousel to extend the full width of the browser window. Using the carousel component from the Bootstrap 4 but the carousel is not wrapping the entire window screen.

What is the best approach in making it full width and responsive? or I'm on the wrong path by putting carousel under 'PageWrap'. But in my opinion, it would not be recommended to put App's component(s) outside the defined container which is 'PageWrap' here.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import "../../src/App.css";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Carousel, CardDeck, Card, Button, Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { TwitterOutlined, FacebookOutlined, YoutubeOutlined, PauseOutlined, SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="PageWrap">
        <content>
<Carousel>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img class= "d-block w-100 h-100" src={require("../Assets/Images/hair_salon_1.jpg").default}/>
</Carousel.Item>
<Carousel.Item>
    <img src={require("../Assets/Images/hair_salon_2.jpg").default}/>
</Carousel.Item>
<Carousel.Item>
    <img src={require("../Assets/Images/hair_salon_3.jpg").default}/>
</Carousel.Item>
  </Carousel>
  </content>
</div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

In order to fix this, what rule(s) need to add to CSS stylesheet to force carousel image to always be full width on screens.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for my, in order to setup a full width page, is switching from

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

It allows carrousel to complete 100% page width.

reference: [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#fluid)